# Почему не работает мой Telegram бот?

Tags: python, telegram, бот

недавно начал изучать создание telegram ботов на python, решил написать простейшего бота, но возникла одна трудность. Вот код:

```
from requests import get

import telebot

bot = telebot.TeleBot("Токен")

@bot.message_handler(commands = ["start"])
def start(message):
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "Привет!")
    bot.send_photo(message.chat.id,get("https://regnum.ru/uploads/pictures/news/2016/08/29/regnum_picture_1472479342755781_normal.jpg").content)


@bot.message_handler(content_types=["text"])
def a(message):
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "Итак, начнём тест! Замечание: отвечай поочерёдно, например: 1)Да... Вопросы:")

    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "1)Ты любишь бобров?")


bot.polling()
```

Почему - то команда start выполняется, а вопрос: "Ты любишь бобров?" не выводится.
Заранее спасибо за ответ!

Comment: Вылетает ли ошибка?

Comment: Вам нужно импортировать types

Answer (score 0):

Вы не импортировали types из pytelegrambotapi.
Вам нужно установить библиотеку **pytelegrambotapi** и добавить строчку кода:

```
from telebot import types
```